# What is the best way to add a custom key mapping in vim/vi? (Does there exist a unbound keyspace for customization?)

Tags: vim, vi, hotkeys

I know you can add custom keymappings to vim with `imap` in the `.vimrc` file. My question is, if one is to create additional custom operators, motions, commands and map them to keys, what is the best way to add them in so they don't conflict with existing bindings?

An analogy, in emacs, a lot of custom key commands are added via the C-c  sequence. To be more technical, are there unbound keys in vim that allow for user customization? In other words, is there a free keyspace available to users?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:imap`<kbd>Enter</kbd> will show a list of your insert mode mappings.

> My question is, if one is to create additional custom operators,
>   motions, commands and map them to keys, what is the best way to add
>   them in so they don't conflict with existing bindings?

In my opinion the best way is creating custom command, they start with uppercase, native ones with lowercase.

---

Additionally, you can use a `<leader>` I use <kbd>,</kbd> some use <kbd>\</kbd>.

e.g. `:let mapleader = ","`

then, you can use the leader to combine it with other keys, like <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to call a command, native or custom, see below:

`:map <leader>p :MyCustomCommand<CR>`

A custom motion example. Delete the third word after the cursor.

`nnoremap <leader>x :normal 2wdw<CR>`

---

Several commands can be used to **create new**, **remove** and **list the mappings**, here is a list of working modes, from `:help map-overview`

```
                                        Normal  Visual+Select  Operator-pending ~
:map   :noremap   :unmap   :mapclear     yes      yes                yes
:nmap  :nnoremap  :nunmap  :nmapclear    yes       -                  -
:vmap  :vnoremap  :vunmap  :vmapclear     -       yes                 -
:omap  :onoremap  :ounmap  :omapclear     -        -                 yes
```

further info
`:help map`

---

Here's an example function, converted to a **custom command**

```
function! MoveLastLines(f)
  exe '$-9,$w ' . a:f    "write last ten lines to the passed filename
  $-9,$d                 "delete last ten lines
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -range MoveTo :call MoveLastLines(<f-args>)
```

Now, both lines below are equivalent

- `:call MoveLastLines('newFile.txt')`
- `:MoveTo newFile.txt`

Comment: That's a very nice answer. I use mappings (with `<Leader>`) for things I know I will need a lot and keep other less used function as commands. Also the `\` mapleader is like that by default.

Comment: @romainl: nice answer but not complete, because it does not mention that `:nunmap can also be used outside of a monastery.` (`:help map-modes`)

Comment: @Benoit, I'm very sorry I missed this detail. As it turns out I was busy looking for my [spoon](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/os_unix.html#spoon) while reading Eric's answer.

Comment: @romainl Can anybody explain what is the point of using `<leader>` anywhere outside published plugins?

Comment: @ZyX I remember you don't like it. I personally use `<leader>` because it gives me a very large set of possibilities for creating my own mappings. Obviously I could use a common "prefix" like `_` or some other available or rarely used key (by me) or even function keys for that purpose but I like to have the same prefix for all those non-native features I use daily. Weither I get them from a plugin or from carefully edited macros or simple things like `"_dP`. However I've only been using Vim for about a year and it's entirely possible that I'm doing things wrong. Why only in plugins?

Comment: @romainl In plugins: because it is first level of settings that are to be used to add customizability to one's plugin mappings (it is not canceling the fact that user may want to have your plugin mappings lack common leader at all). Not in plugins: because when you define some mapping and use it often you put it in «finger memory». You won't thank yourself when it will break because `<leader>` changed (if you, for example, use plugin mappings less often then your ones and once decide to keep them separate by changing `<leader>`). It is the reason why I won't ever use leader for my mappings.

Comment: @romainl s/add customizability/use one common behavior pattern so that plugin's behavior won't be unexpected and &/