# vim mappings nightmare

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using MacVim and I am trying to change the basic default key mappings, but I am failing miserably. I dont know why it's so complicated. This is what I am trying to do: (please tell me what to put in my .gvimrc)

- remap Home to ^ (use in imode and end up in imode as well)
- remap End to $ (use in imode and end up in imode as well)
- remap Shift+anyArrowKey to the usual select things (use in imode and end up in imode as well)

Basically, I am trying to get usual edit functionality to macvim.

Keep in mind that some kind of unmappings need to happen first. I already tried just adding mappings, but it doesnt work.

If you could paste a section that I could just copy/paste to my .gvimrc file, that would be great.

This is how my mappings look like:  (from running :map)

```
 n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
       <M-Down>      }
       <D-Down>    * <C-End>
       <M-Up>        {
       <D-Up>      * <C-Home>
       <M-Right>   * <C-Right>
       <D-Right>   * <End>
       <M-Left>    * <C-Left>
       <D-Left>    * <Home>
    n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
    v  <BS>          "-d
    v  <D-x>         "*d
    v  <D-c>         "*y
    v  <D-v>         "-d"*P
    n  <D-v>         "*P
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7784993/529725

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't do that and learn Vim instead: while what you want is very easy to do, it's also **a very very bad idea**.

Vim draws a large part of its power from a strict separation between what can/should be done in *insert* mode (inserting text) and what can/should be done in *normal* mode (navigation, yanking, pasting, deleting…). Modal editing can be weird in the beginning but you'll get used to it soon and swear by it later. It's only a matter of time.

I've done exactly what you ask and more (tried to change all Vim mappings to TM ones) when I switched from TextMate until I realized it was the most counter-productive thing to do.

If you really don't like (or don't want to adjust to) modal editing, there are many text editors out there which will let you use your keyboard "normally" *and* have lots of powerful features.

That said, here are some pointers:

```
:h key-notation
:h mapping
```

and you don't need any unmappings.

Comment: The reason why i used to use "Vim Easy" on my Windows installation (recently moved to Mac), is because "Vim Easy" was the only editor that could: 1. open a very large txt file in a short time. 2. has bracket, parenthesis and etc matching. 3. has line wrapping at whole words that works. 4. has a search capability that works. 5. has line numbering that works (each line with a number, even if the line wraps).  If you know of a lightweight (basic text manipulation, dont need rich-format or fancy options), then please do tell. I have been searching for some days now.

Comment: As for learning two-mode, I would say that is a preference thing. I worked with basic vi last summer and I didnt get used to it. Only hate it more now. So you like two-mode, other people (like me) don't.

Comment: I am still looking for a "script" that would do all the mentioned remappings, btw.

Comment: Vim is modal. If you don't like this basic fact and persist in trying to use it differently than it was designed you are facing lots of hours of frustration.

Comment: Vim doesn't give line numbers to the "virtual" wrapped lines. What do you call "a very large txt file"? Search "works" in every editor I've ever used, did you try TextWrangler? Smultron? Also, Vim's modal editing is not something some Vim users like and some dislike: it's at the core of using Vim. The divide is more like "some people like it and use Vim, most people don't like it and don't use Vim". I'm not being smug here: trying to make Vim into a "normal" editor is an exercise in futility. It simply can't work.

Comment: "Vim Easy" is just GVim started with the `-y` flag. MacVim is distributed with a `mvim` script. Put it in your `$PATH` and execute it in the terminal: `$ mvim -y` to have a new MacVim window that works like "Vim Easy". To know where you should put `mvim`, type `$ echo $PATH` in a terminal window to get a list of folders. Put `mvim` in one of these and open a new terminal window.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I was looking for :)  However... Home, End, Shift+Up, Shift+Down, Shift+Home, Shift+End still dont work. Also , how can I integrate the -y option so it will take effect when I launch MacVim from the icon and also from "Open With..." menu ?